# SignalR server to server communications

Tags: .net-core, signalr, blazor

I have an application that uses SignalR to broadcast data to all connected clients. Its a .NET6 Blazor Wasm hosted web application. Now, I want the the broadcaster (which is running on the Blazor server) to connect to a data source that is outside my website, and get data from there. The source data is being broadcast via UDP on a different network.

So my question is, is it possible that my SignalR hub that is running on the Blazor server connects to another SignalR hub running on a different machine in a different network and get real time data from it? Or may be I can run a SignalR client as well on my Blazor server and then connect to a machine on another network? Can I run a SignalR hub on the UDP source machine to which my Blazor server SignalR hub or client can connect? From what I have read, SignalR only runs on a website. Or is it that SignalR is not suitable for this kind of server to server data feeds?

Comment: You can certainly broadcast from a server.  I can't see why you cannot also set up a "client" service on the server to connect to the second server and then some sort of orchestration service between that and the hubcontext.